# Executable R script with Mac OSX having problems

Tags: r, macos, bash, shell, executable

I'm trying to write a simple double-clickable `file.command` on my Mac OSX machine.  Here is my shell script on the `.command` file:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env Rscript
 Rscript /Users/MyName/Dropbox/Workout_log_script/workout_log.R
```

And here is the error I get:

```
 MyName$ /Users/MyName/Desktop/workout_plotter.command ; exit;
 Error: object 'Rscript' not found
 Execution halted
 logout
```

I don't have much experience with using `bash`.  Does anyone know how I can fix this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing two possible ways to do it:

either write a Bash script that launches the `Rscript` utility:

```
#!/bin/bash
Rscript /Users/MyName/Dropbox/Workout_log_script/workout_log.R
```

making sure `Rscript` is available from the `$PATH` and the Bash script is executable ; or

make the `R` script executable and add the so-called shebang

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
```

at the first line of the `R` script. The `R` script will then be runnable by double clicking it.

Answer (score 1):

your interpreter string is not ok for bash use `/usr/bin/Rscript`

and make your script executable whit `chmod 755 <script>`